# Passagem de Parâmetro na URL usando JSON + AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Estou estudando JavaScript e gostaria de um suporte de vocês.

Tenho um arquivo que chamei de `getPagamentosMaioresQue.php`, esse arquivo tem a seguinte sintaxe:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
     <title> PHP Trabalhando com Arrays</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php require_once("Pagamentos.class.php");

            $valorPagamento = $_GET['valor'];

            $objPagamentos = new Pagamentos();
            $objPagamentos->pesquisaPagamentosMaioresQue($valorPagamento);

        ?>
    </body>

</html>
```

....e tenho outro arquivo chamado `grafico.php` onde chamo o arquivo acima usando essa parte do código...

```js
function desenhaGraficoPagamentos(){
                var jsonData = $.ajax({
                    url: "getPagamentosMaioresQue.php",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false
                }).responseText;
```

Acontece que quando eu uso o `getPagamentosMaioresQue.php?valor=10` funciona normalmente....

Quero saber como passo esses parâmetros para esse arquivo através do `grafico.php?valor=10`?

Comment: Como seu arquivo grafico.php está incluído na página? require/include ou <script....?

Comment: Estou chamando o arquivo grafico.php é chamado diretamente...

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> PHP Trabalhando com Arrays</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php require_once("Pagamentos.class.php");
            $valorPagamento = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'VALOR',FILTER_DEFAULT);
            $objPagamentos = new Pagamentos();
            $objPagamentos->pesquisaPagamentosMaioresQue($valorPagamento);

        ?>
    </body>

</html>
```

```js
function desenhaGraficoPagamentos(){
                var jsonData = $.ajax({
                    url: "getPagamentosMaioresQue.php",
                    async: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: valor=400, 
                }).responseText;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function desenhaGraficoPagamentos(){
                var jsonData = $.ajax({
                    url: "getPagamentosMaioresQue.php",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false,
                    data: valor, 
                }).responseText;
```

adiciona a propriedade data no $.ajax Onde essa variável (valor) adicionada como parametro no seu $.ajax  seria valor recebido pelo teu arquivo grafico.php

Comment: Olá Sam, bom dia. Mas como eu faço para que a variável "valor" seja usada pelo arquivo `getPagamentosMaioresQue.php`?

Comment: você pode colocar                data: "<?php  $_GET['valor'] ?>"

Comment: no teu arquivo getPagamentosMaioresQue.php é só pegar os dados usando um desses metodos   $_POST["data"];  ou $GET["data"].